# Swift error "Immutable value only has mutating members"

Tags: macos, swift

When compiling the following Swift code (in Sample.swift):

```
import Cocoa

class Sample {
    func doSomething() {
        var stringArray = Array<String>()
        stringArray.append("AAA")
        addToString(stringArray)
        stringArray.append("CCC")
    }

    func addToString(myArray:Array<String>) {
        myArray.append("BBB")
    }
}
```

I get the following error on the line 'myArray.append("BBB")':

```
Immutable value of type 'Array<String>' only has mutating members named 'append'
```

How do I fix the code to allow a call to this mutable method?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to modify the array you have to specify it as in an inout parameter like this `func addToString(inout myArray:Array<String>)`. Then when you call the function you have to add & in front of your argument to show that it can be modified by the function. Your code will look something like this:

```
class Sample {
    func doSomething() {
        var stringArray = Array<String>()
        stringArray.append("AAA")
        addToString(&stringArray)
        stringArray.append("CCC")
    }

    func addToString(inout myArray:Array<String>) {
        myArray.append("BBB")
    }
}
```

You may want to take a look at in-out parameters on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html).

Comment: Fantastic! Making the parameter "inout" (and passing it using "&") worked perfectly.  Many thanks for that.

Comment: Here is a version of the answer that works with Swift 3: 
`class Sample {`
    `func doSomething() {`
        `var stringArray = [String]()`
        `stringArray.append("AAA")`
        `addToString(withMyArray: &stringArray)`
        `stringArray.append("CCC")`
    `}`

    `func addToString(withMyArray myArray: inout [String]) {`
        `myArray.append("BBB")`
    `}`
`}`